# Is it okay to say 'whether on phone or via email'?

Tags: whether

I'm writing a cover letter, and the sentence I'm trying to fix is the below one.

> I am fully capable of working using English whether on phone or via
>   email thanks to my work experience.

Is it okay to say "whether on phone or via email" and does it sound natural to add "thanks to my work experience" at the end? I just felt that the grammar may be wrong or a bit awkward. Please help me with this one!

Comment: You can send messages *via* email, but I don't think two people can work together *via* email. Changing the preposition to *in, by* or *on* makes the sentence sound much better.

Comment: @PeterShor - I am envisioning an interface  to bash where I send shell commands via email and it emails me back the output.:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would be inclined to say

> As a result of my work experience, I am fully capable of working using English either by phone or email

Answer (score -1):

This is my best stab at it:

> *As a result of my work experience, I am quite comfortable*
>   *communicating in English, whether it be by phone or via email.*